# Reading JSONP with Dojo Dojo.io.script

Tags: ajax, dojo, jsonp

I would like to use DOJO to access JSONP data returning from the following url:

http://api.metro.net/agencies/lametro/routes/704/vehicles/callback=recover

Here is my simple dojo.io.script.get function:

```
dojo.io.script.get({
url: "http://api.metro.net/agencies/lametro/routes/704/vehicles/",
content: {callback: "recover"},
callbackParamName: "callback",
load: function(data){
    console.log('OK', data);
},
error: function(error){
    console.log('Error', error);
});
```

I am getting a "SyntaxError: invalid label"; apparently the server is sending JSON instead of JSONP.

What is the correct format of dojo.io.script.get in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (assuming dojo 1.7/AMD):

```
require(["dojo/io/script"], function (ioScript) {

                        ioScript.get({
                            url: "http://api.metro.net/agencies/lametro/routes/704/vehicles/callback=recover",
                            content: { callback: "recover" }
                            , callbackParamName: "callback"
                            , load: function (data) {
                                console.log('OK', data);
                            }
                            , error: function(error) {
                                console.log('Error', error);
                                }
                            });
                    });
```

Basically the problem was how to send that callback parameter to the server.

Enjoy,